# Pulseaudio persistent hw name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

I am trying to design a system that plays multiple parallel streams of audio via multiple USB audio outputs. I have my laptop setup with 4 usb audio devices connected. Currently I am using

pacmd list-sinks

```
index: 2
    name: <alsa_output.usb-GeneralPlus_USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9049
```

...

I run the audio using

```
$ PULSE_SINK=2 vlc audio.ogg
or
$ PULSE_SINK=1 vlc audio.ogg
```

My problem is that, at each reboot, the indexes returned by pacmd list-sinks are different for different ports. Thus I am not able to determine which port would play for PULSE_SINK=2 (for eg.).

Is there a way to set a persistent name for a hardware id and reuse it each time my machine reboots.

eg. 
    $ PULSE_SINK=usbdevice1 vlc audio.ogg